# IIS 7 IP address forwarding

Tags: iis, dns, ip

I want to move some websites from server 1 to server 2.

My clients have A records pointing to the IP address of server 1. Without updating their DNS records, how can I automatically forward request for those domains from server 1 to server 2?

Thanks

Graham

Comment: Do you need me to add anything further to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This image is from [an article regarding Exchange](http://theucguy.net/redirecting-owa-urls-in-exchange-2010/), but the IIS settings are relevant.

You can redirect at the HTTP level by specifying a URL redirect in IIS's **HTTP Redirect** settings:-

[image: HTTP Redirects in IIS]

However, for this approach to work you will need a new domain for your sites. e.g. if the A record resolves `www.example.com` to `Server 1`  you will need to redirect to another URL (e.g. `www.example.edu`) that already resolves to `Server 2`.

Another option is to [setup a reverse proxy](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx) using IIS on `Server 1`:

> Today there was a question in the IIS.net Forums asking how to expose two different Internet sites from another site making them look like if they were subdirectories in the main site.
>
> So for example the goal was to have a site: `www.site.com` expose a `www.site.com/company1` and a `www.site.com/company2` and have the content from `www.company1.com` served for the first one and `www.company2.com` served in the second one

So slightly different requirements (the article only wants a subdirectory rather than the whole site), but the same concept will apply.