# IIS 8 keep asking for credentials for windows authentication

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have a web site hosted in one of the local servers recently we did a change where it redirects to a custom page when I login to the actual server and navigating it works as expected. Where as when I am using outside the server like

https://mysite/sa/sites/siteName/#admin

it keeps on asking for username and password, I am using windows authentication, I tired all the options available as per the sources from stack over flow and other but nothing works

[How to allow anonymous access to web-site on IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326076/how-to-allow-anonymous-access-to-web-site-on-iis-7-5)
[Windows Authentication not working on local IIS 7.5. Error 401.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466665/windows-authentication-not-working-on-local-iis-7-5-error-401-1)

I tried changing the permissions on the folder by giving IUSER as full access and changing it to applicationidentity but nothing works

Here is authentication set at different level

[image: Website level]

[image: Site root level]

[[image: Actual site level3]

Comment: could you please enable failed request tracing rule in iis for the 200-500 error code and reproduce the issue to see what is the error code

Comment: OK I tried this but no luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450034/iis-7-ip-address-forwarding I will check the tracing

Comment: I added this in config and it works `<rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="Maintenance.htm" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>`

Comment: If you're using Windows Authentication, you should disable Anonymous